# pip install error ubuntu 15.10 ( Pillow )

Tags: python, 15.10, pip

When I try to install something with pip I have error. But with sudo everything is ok.
pip install pillow

```
Downloading/unpacking pillow
  Downloading Pillow-3.1.1.tar.gz (10.1MB): 10.1MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-hFguWU/pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package pillow
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
Installing collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py install for pillow
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
   ***//a lot of errors like this***
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Qunused-arguments'
```

Comment: "But with sudo everything is ok" so there is no problem?

Comment: Nope. I working with django and I must start server with sudo, so all files created can't be changed without root

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install Pillow==2.9.0` 
I had the same issue when I typed `pip install Pillow` which installs latest version of it.